# NullException error. Help a noob out

Tags: c#, xna, argumentnullexception

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong here? I keep receiving the error message:

> "ArgumentNullException was unhandled. This method does not accept null
>   for this parameter. Parameter name: song"

I cannot find a way around it.

```
Song BGmusic;
bool songstart = false;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    currentgamescreen = Gamescreen.menuscreen;

    if (!songstart)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(BGmusic);
    }

    BGmusic = Game.Content.Load<Song>("audio/rockTheDragon");
}
```

Comment: is `BGmusic` initialized anywhere?

Comment: Just another improvement: I'd set the bool `songstart` to true as well  when you start the song!

Comment: Its clear in the context of this code that `BGmusic` is null when `MediaPlayer.Play` is called.  Why are you not checking to see if the file needs to be loaded or has already been loaded before playing the file.   Your logic makes zero sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you call `MediaPlayer.Play(BGmusic);` where `BGmusic` not yet intialized, so null.

*Probabbly* making it like:

```
protected override void LoadContent()
{
    currentgamescreen = Gamescreen.menuscreen;

    if (!songstart)
    {
        BGmusic = Game.Content.Load<Song>("audio/rockTheDragon");
        MediaPlayer.Play(BGmusic);
    }
 }
```

will resolve a problem.

Comment: This has worked, thanks very much @Tigran. Knew it would be something simple, but I've been at it all day and I'm starting to go crazy! Currently working on: MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `MediaPlayer.Play(BGmusic)` before assigning a value to `BGmusic`. Try the following:

```
Song BGmusic;
bool songstart = false;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
    currentgamescreen = Gamescreen.menuscreen;

    BGmusic = Game.Content.Load<Song>("audio/rockTheDragon");

    if (!songstart)
    {
        MediaPlayer.Play(BGmusic);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move

```
 BGmusic = Game.Content.Load<Song>("audio/rockTheDragon");
```

To the top of that method